# Child components return null in parent form angular 4/5

Tags: angular

I have this reusable component that simply will let the user select some records.

While the records in child component are correctly displayed, the selected/entered data always returns null.

Here is a slimmed down structure of both (with some elements removed for space purposes)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {GlobalData} from '../../../globals/global-data';
import { ControlContainer, FormGroupName  } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hr',
  templateUrl: './hr.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hr.component.scss'],
  viewProviders: [
    { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupName  }
  ]
})

export class HrComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor() {}
}
```

the html:

```
<select formControlName="rec">
  <option value="1">Lower</option>
  <option value="2">Higher</option>
</select>
```

Parent.component.ts

```
this.rForm = fb.group({      
  'hr': fb.group ({
        'rec' : [null, []],

      }),      
  'reason':[null,[Validators.required]]
});

processForm(post){
    console.log(post.hr); //===================>returns null for all child elements tho selected
}
```

Parent.html

```
 <form [formGroup]="rForm" (ngSubmit)="processForm(rForm.value)">

  <div formGroupName="hr">
  <app-hr></app-hr>
  </div>

  <input type="text" formControlName="reason"/>

 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but I think you should use Output() in child component, and emit the selected value: `this.example.emit(value);` , and listen in parent component?

Comment: Oh there is no way without emit? Ok, let me try that.

Comment: @NieSelam that is the way parent/child components communicate. There is also a way to create a communication service, but that is mostly used to communicate between components on different levels/places, for parent/child this is a good way.